# Calculate result of two values on Property Changed MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, propertychanged

I am trying to Calculate the "NetAmount" by the following simple formula in MVVM

> GrossAmount + Carriage - Discount = NetAmount

I am using MVVM Light Toolkit and declared properties as follows

```
public const string DiscountPropertyName = "Discount";
private double _discount;
public double Discount
{
    get
    {
        return _discount;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_discount == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _discount = value;
        // Update bindings, no broadcast
        RaisePropertyChanged(DiscountPropertyName);
    }
}

public const string CarriagePropertyName = "Carriage";
private double _carriage;

public double Carriage
{
    get
    {
        return _carriage;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_carriage == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _carriage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(CarriagePropertyName);
    }
}

public const string NetAmountPropertyName = "NetAmount";
private double _netAmount;

public double NetAmount
{
    get
    {
        _netAmount = Carriage + Discount;
        return _netAmount;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_netAmount == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _netAmount = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(NetAmountPropertyName);
    }
}

public const string GrossAmountPropertyName = "GrossAmount";
private double _grossAmount;

public double GrossAmount
{
    get
    {
        return _grossAmount;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_grossAmount == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _grossAmount = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(GrossAmountPropertyName);
    }
}
```

I Bind these properties in XAML with text boxes like follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding GrossAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Carriage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Discount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

And I bind a Text Block with the `NetAmount` Property like follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding NetAmount}" />
```

The ViewModel is `SalesOrderViewModel`.

I dont know where do I put the above mentioned formula so that it when any of the text boxes value is changed, it result in changing the `NetAmount` Property.

I am not new to C# but am new to MVVM and `PropertyChanged` Events, I know there is some really small silly thing I am doing wrong but cant get my head around it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `NetAmount` is a calculation it makes sense to model it as a read only property in your view model. Accessing the property actually performs the calculation. The last trick is to call `RaisePropertyChanged(NetAmountProperty)` whenever any of the factors that affects `NetAmount` changes

```
public const string GrossAmountPropertyName = "GrossAmount";
private double _grossAmount;
public double GrossAmount
{
    get { return _grossAmount; }
    set 
    {
           if (_grossAmount == value)
                return;

           RaisePropertyChanged(GrossAmountPropertyName);
           RaisePropertyChanged(NetAmountPropertyName);
    }
}

public double Discount{} ... //Implement same as above
public double Carriage {} ... //Implement same as above

public const string NetAmountPropertyName = "NetAmount";
public double NetAmount
{
    get { return GrossAmount + Carriage - Discount; }
}
```

---

Edit: If you don't want to add a call to `RaisePropertyChanged` to every property that affects the NetAmount then you could modify `RaisePropertyChanged` so that it also raises a `PropertyChanged` event for the `NetAmount` property. It will cause some unnecessary `PropertyChanged` events to be raised but will be more maintainable

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(NetAmountProperty);
     }
}
```

Comment: Great, Thanks, not only solved my problem but also help me understand the concept

Comment: I have the same problem, and had considered that solution but rejected it. The trouble is that the public property GrossAmount needs to know about everything that uses it, which seems to me to be very poor practice. If any new client uses GrossAmount, the code for GrossAmount needs to be changed. :(

Comment: @pickles: Yes, I'd come to the conclusion that was the way to do it, and if there are lots of such calculations going on to refactor them into their own classes.